# Cannot disable some stylecop rules in Rider

Tags: .net-core, stylecop, rider

Lets say we have a rule SA1402FileMayOnlyContainASingleTypea.

We have too classes in one file, resulting in Error. We want to fix it from Rider (don't know how VS will behave), I click context menu ->Inspection->'Disable once with comment'->'Disable in file with comment'. It generates: "**// ReSharper disable SA1402**", but even after recompiling everything it stil shows an Error.

What fixes is comment "**#pragma warning disable SA1402**"

Comment: I found a related Youtrack issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-26493

Answer (score 0):

My issue was due to the flag

```
Rider Settings > Editor > Inspection Settings > Read settings from editorconfig ...
```

was not set.

When I enabled it, the StyleCop.Analyzer settings file applied fine.